# Cross domain Ajax class

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain

Sure this question has been asked before but i could not find an answer to it. I have an iframe which can be embed on a customer's site. I want to be able to submit the form data back to my site. I thought Ajax could solve it but it has cross domain issues. I also read about jsonp, but it is confusing. Is there any class i could use for ajax cross domain posting or a good tutorial to read.

Comment: is the iframe hosted on your site ?

Comment: Why do you need to cross domain AJAX when you have embedded the form via an iframe? As in can't you submit the form in that iframe in pure html way?

Comment: @user576875: The iframe is hosted on my site.

Comment: @mhitza: The iframe opens an overlay with the form. The overlay cannot submit the form without closing. So i want to submit it with Ajax instead.

Answer (score 0):

The iframe is hosted on your own site, so you don't need cross-domain ajax to make ajax requests back to your site from the context of the iframe.